# Can I install binary only drivers in Gentoo Linux?

Tags: software-installation, drivers, gentoo, binary

I am considering Gentoo Linux as a possible candidate for my system. The only doubt I have at this point is about binary tools.
Being Gentoo a source based distribution to be built from scratch, can it use externally developed binary only tools, such as proprietary (graphics card) drivers?

Comment: Yes. Example: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/NVIDIA/nvidia-drivers

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa - If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. While Gentoo is a source-based distro, it does support binary tools and drivers. As an example, here's how to use the proprietary NVIDIA drivers: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/NVIDIA/nvidia-drivers